# WordPressで新規ページを作成するのに困っています。

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

今度は`WordPress`を始めました。
（というかやらざるを得なくなりました・・・）

ちなみに私、HTMLもCSSもPHPも超初心者で、さらにWordPressなるものを初めて触ります。

現在制作中のWebサイトですが、基本的にはほぼ全て静的なHTMLとCSSで作成しております。
デザインはWebデザイナーがおりますので、その方にお任せしています。
（一部PHPを使っておりますが、大したことはしていません）

やりたいことは、ユーザーさんが自分で新しいページを作りたいと考えたときに
WordPressを使って新規ページを作成するのですが、Wordpressの例えば

> **固定ページの新規追加でタイトルと内容を入力すれば、新規ページが出来上がる**

ということがしたいのです。
そして制作中の静的HTMLよりリンクを貼ってWordPressで作成した新規ページに飛ぶようにします。

ただ、このときの条件ですが、添付した図のように`ヘッダー部`、`グローバルナビゲーション`
`サイドメニュー`、`フッター部`は既に仕上がっているHTMLのデザインを踏襲したいのです。
要するに他のページも同じようなレイアウトになっているので、ページが変わっても
上記の箇所だけは固定で表示するようにしたいです。

そして、WordPresの固定ページ機能で入力した文章等が

> **添付図の「Ａ」のところに表示される**

ようにしたいです。

上記を実現するために、

> **特殊な方法ではなく、一般的に用いる方法**

をご教授ください。
※特殊な方法だと、私が理解できないので・・・

お手数ですが、宜しくお願い致します。

【開発環境】

- レンタルサーバー（CentOS 5）
- WordPress（4.1.1）
- PHP（5.2.16）
- HTML
- CSS
- 作業環境（Windows7pro）
- PHP編集用（NoEditor）
- ブラウザ（FireFox）

**追記**
　どうやら質問の範囲があまりも広すぎたことに気づきました。
　ですので、少し質問の内容を変えます。
　今回の質問した内容を解決するための、参考にすべきサイトがありましたら
　ご教授ください。
　もう既に `webdesignrecipes.com/first-time-wordpress-origin-theme`
　というサイトをご紹介いただいたのですが、他にもありましたら教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「既存の静的サイトのデザインに合わせてWordpressサイトを構築したい」ということなら、テーマを作れば概ね解決できるのではないでしょうか http://webdesignrecipes.com/first-time-wordpress-origin-theme/

Comment: なるほど、他のWebサイトを参照していましたが、今回教えていただいたサイトは何となく分かり易そうな感じがしますので、じっくりと見てみます。どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTMLですでにコーディングされたページを、WordPressで動くようにされたいという認識であっていますでしょうか？
もしこのやり方であれば、「[本格ビジネスサイトを作りながら学ぶ WordPressの教科書](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/479736758X) 」の内容が比較的近いものかなと思います。
ただWordPress系の入門書は合う合わないがかなり強い印象がありますので、書店などで一度中身をご覧になられてからのほうがよいかもしれません。

またWordPressをはじめとするOSSでは専用のサポートフォーラムが設けられていることが多いですので、
実装時に出てきた不明な点などはこちらに質問されてみてはいかがでしょうか？
http://ja.forums.wordpress.org/

Comment: なるほど、そういう本もあるのですね。書店に行って確認してみます。あと、WordPressのサポートフォーラムもあるそうで、こちらの方も確認して閾値が低かったら利用してみようと思います。